# How to delay on checkform using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to delay for 10 sec before submit form like this but not work. It's will be still return true by not to delay.

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkform(this);" >
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
</form>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function checkform ( form )
    {
        var test = "1";
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(test != '0'){
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }, 10000);
    }
</script>
```

I want to know, how to delay on checkform using javascript ?

Comment: What is your objective here? you are just returning true/false. What is the point of the delay?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn actually nothing is returned to the outer function

Comment: What's calling checkform? If it's bound to your form's submit event, you need to cancel its default behaviour using preventDefault().

Comment: You can't in this way delay the return statement. Whenever you call `setTimeout` or any other asynchronous function, the code will move ahead to next statements in the function and return undefined if nothing else has been returned outside the `setTimeout` block.

Comment: you should `e.preventdefault()` or `return false` inside it and then submit it with delay untill then it wont work, assuming you are trying to use it with submit button

Answer (score 0):

You must return to the `checkForm` function. A `return` inside a callback does not return to the outer function. Even if it did it must be immediate, not 10 seconds later

You could use a flag so you can call the function again inside the delay by submitting the form again

```
var allowSubmit = false;

function checkform(form) {
  if (allowSubmit) {
    return true;
  } else {
    var test = "1";
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (test === '1') {
        // when validation passes resubmit with updated flag
        allowSubmit = true;
        form.submit();
      }
    }, 10000);

    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here is that a submit request is has the same outcome as if you were to return something in a function.

For example if you had something like this:

```
function returnExplanation(){

    return 0;
    console.log("You will never see me");

}
```

You will never see the text in the console after the return.

A submit functions the same. although there are a few other ways to make this happen, I made a few adjustments to your code to achieve what you were looking for.

```
 <form class="form" id="submitForm" method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data">
        <input type="button" name="submit" value="OK">
    </form>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#submitForm').on('click', function ()
            {
                var test = 1;
                setTimeout(
                        function ()
                        {
                            if (test !== 0)
                            {
                                console.log("false");
                                return false;
                            } else
                            {
                                console.log("true");
                                return true;
                            }
                        }, 10000);
                $('#submitForm').submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The first thing I did was give your form an "id". this allows jQuery (or javascript) to easily decipher exactly which element they should be communicating with.

Next, I removed your "onsubmit" attribute and added the appropriate jQuery to respond to the click event.

After that, I changed your button from a "submit" to a "button" type.

lastly, after the timeout, your form still submits with the line that reads:

```
 $('#submitForm').submit();
```

I hope this helps you on your way to becoming a  better HTML / jQuery programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better way to do it if you have jQuery library included. In your case, the page gets submitted to itself and gets refreshed, so your 10 seconds get reset.

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="" enctype = "multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
</form>

$(function(){
   $("form").bind("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var test = "1";
        setTimeout(function(){ 
           if(test != '0'){
                //return false;
                alert("false");
            }else{
                 alert("true")
                //return true;
            } 
        }, 10000);
    });
});
```